# 6 different positive numbers; sum = product

Tags: elementary-number-theory, products

As the title says, I want to know if there exists a set of 6 DIFFERENT POSITIVE numbers such that their sum equals their product. (a+b+c+d+e+f=abcdef)

Comment: Real numbers? Or integer numbers?

Comment: Real numbers, for example 0.5 would fit

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you choose $a, b, c, d, e$ randomly and solve for $f$, you will almost surely get something different from your first five numbers, and there's at least a good chance it will be positive.

For example, for $a=1$, $b=2$, $c=3$, $d=4$, $e=5$ (not very random, but works well enough) we get
$$ 15+f = 120 f$$
which we can solve to get $f=\frac{15}{119}$.

---

This can be extended to show that there is a sequence of *distinct positive rational numbers* $(a_i)_{i\in\mathbb N}$ such that
$$ \sum_{i=1}^n a_i = \prod_{i=1}^n a_i $$
for all $n\ge 1$.

Comment: See e.g. OEIS sequence [A225156](http://oeis.org/A225156).

Answer (score 0):

Let $C=\sqrt[\Large5]{\dfrac{1+2+\dotsb+6}{1\times2\times\dotsb\times6}}$. That is, let $C=\sqrt[\Large5]{\dfrac{21}{720}}\approx0.49315$. Then the following works:
\begin{align}
a&=\phantom1C\\
b&=2C\\
c&=3C\\
d&=4C\\
e&=5C\\
f&=6C
\end{align}